# Hadoop Container's features

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

Hadoop create container for processing each task.container's properties are different.
I want to know container's properties of each task in Hadoop.for example the Ram,cpu ,....

does any body knows tools for it ?

thanks

Comment: Do you want use yarn?

Comment: do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Bash is your friend:

CPU_MILLISECONDS for cpu usage

```
hadoop job -counter <job-id> org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter CPU_MILLISECONDS
```

PHYSICAL_MEMORY_BYTES for memory usage

```
hadoop job -counter <job-id> org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter PHYSICAL_MEMORY_BYTES
```

Comment: thanks,container is for tasks, and I want the cpu usage and Ram for each task,

Comment: does it show the container for each tasks?both commands are the same,does it correct?

Comment: I tested it , it shows error!!!!!hadoop job -counter <job_1488455362111_0001> org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter CPU_MILLISECONDS
bash: job_1488455362111_0001: No such file or directory

Comment: Without '<' '>'

Comment: ~/hadoop/bin/hadoop job -counter job_1488455362111_0001 org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter PHYSICAL_MEMORY_BYTES
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute mapred command is deprecated.
Instead use the mapred command for it.

17/03/03 03:55:26 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
17/03/03 03:55:26 INFO mapred.ClientServiceDelegate: Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
657403904